# How to run my thread even during device Switch-Off in android

Tags: android, multithreading, date, utc, runnable

I have developed an application that runs every day once. In that I want to update the date by one in a File (so it needs to be done every day).
I make it possible with help of Handler like this:

```
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try{

                FileInputStream fia = openFileInput("ActualDate");
                StringBuffer actualContent = new StringBuffer("");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    while ((fia.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        actualContent.append(new String(buffer));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                actualDate = actualContent.toString().trim();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                try {
                    c.setTime(sdf.parse(actualDate));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
                actualDate = sdf.format(c.getTime()); 
                FileOutputStream foa = openFileOutput("ActualDate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                foa.write(actualDate.getBytes());
                foa.close();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                startupFunction();
            }

        }
    };

    long delay = 24*60*60*1000; // first run after a day

    long period = 24*60*60*1000; // repeat every day.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

        mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }

    }, delay, period);
```

The actual idea behind this is that I want a device independent date for my application which user cannot change. I store the first occurrence of date in **ActualDate** file from UTC date.

**PROBLEM:** The code works fine except when device is switched off and so thread stops for that time. How can I overcome this problem.

All kinds of suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow the logic below. Its just a thought, which may be helpful.

Your application runs today - So you put an entry in your file, say **myTodayDate**. This is your application specific date.

Along with this, also put the system current date, which will be stored as **lastUpdatedDate**.

Say the mobile stays switched off for next 2 days. Later, when your application runs, you can do this.

Take the **lastUpdatedDate** from the file and subtract it from the current system date. The difference you'll get will be as **noOfDays=2**.

Add this to your **myTodayDate** which is there in your file.

Now, store this new date, along with current system as told before. This may help you overcome your date sync problem.

Just a thought actually! Let me know, if it helped.

Comment: Brilliant Idea !! Let me try it !

Comment: @R.J-Hey I need ur help here, the Runnable thread gets killed automatically after 3-4 days...how to ensure that it lasts for minimum 15 days..??

Answer (score 1):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to have your application run periodically instead of all the time. Using delays like you are in your code will waste cycles and your application risks being killed by the Android OS itself because of memory management.

Comment: I dont want any UI to be handled...just the File should get updated to time including the time when device was switched off..!!

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid: consider what you would do if the phone was *actually switched off, no power*. Then do that.

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid if you combine this with `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent filter, and RJ's answer to check the last updated date it will work best.

Comment: @danada-Hey I need ur help here, the Runnable thread gets killed automatically after 3-4 days...how to ensure that it lasts for minimum 15 days..?? Can I do this with AlarmManager..??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid the idea is that you don't run it as a runnable thread, but instead, more of a scheduled thing. Using AlarmManager, you can schedule tasks to happen in the future. You'll still have to implement the checks RJ suggested to calculate days since last boot.

Comment: @danada-I just want to know that is it possible to schedule a task every day at exactly at a predefined time say 1:00am daily for infinite days without being stopped..??

Comment: @danada-Also How can I work with AlarmManager if I dont want Service or Receiver (as I need to do some work with GUI)...???

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid taken directly from the AlarmManager documentation: _The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a **specific time**, even if your application is not currently running._ So yes, for your first question. Second, you have to make your app handle the intent from the AlarmManager. What you do with it is up to you. You can start an activity, or just run some stuff in the background.